# Why python2 shows \r (Raw escaped) and python3 does not?

Tags: python, string, escaping

I have been having a path error: ***No file or directory found*** for hours. After hours of debugging, I realised that python2 added an invisible `'\r'` at the end of each line.

The input: (trainval.txt)

```
Images/K0KKI1.jpg Labels/K0KKI1.xml
Images/2KVW51.jpg Labels/2KVW51.xml
Images/MMCPZY.jpg Labels/MMCPZY.xml
Images/LCW6RB.jpg Labels/LCW6RB.xml
```

The code I used to debug the error

```
with open('trainval.txt', "r") as lf:
 for line in lf.readlines():
  print ((line),repr(line))
  img_file, anno = line.strip("\n").split(" ")
  print(repr(img_file), repr(anno))
```

Python2 output:

```
("'Images/K0KKI1.jpg'", "'Labels/K0KKI1.xml\\r'")
('Images/2KVW51.jpg Labels/2KVW51.xml\r\n', "'Images/2KVW51.jpg Labels/2KVW51.xml\\r\\n'")
("'Images/2KVW51.jpg'", "'Labels/2KVW51.xml\\r'")
('Images/MMCPZY.jpg Labels/MMCPZY.xml\r\n', "'Images/MMCPZY.jpg Labels/MMCPZY.xml\\r\\n'")
("'Images/MMCPZY.jpg'", "'Labels/MMCPZY.xml\\r'")
('Images/LCW6RB.jpg Labels/LCW6RB.xml\r\n', "'Images/LCW6RB.jpg Labels/LCW6RB.xml\\r\\n'")
("'Images/LCW6RB.jpg'", "'Labels/LCW6RB.xml\\r'")
```

Python3 output:

```
Images/K0KKI1.jpg Labels/K0KKI1.xml
 'Images/K0KKI1.jpg Labels/K0KKI1.xml\n'
'Images/K0KKI1.jpg' 'Labels/K0KKI1.xml'
Images/2KVW51.jpg Labels/2KVW51.xml
 'Images/2KVW51.jpg Labels/2KVW51.xml\n'
'Images/2KVW51.jpg' 'Labels/2KVW51.xml'
Images/MMCPZY.jpg Labels/MMCPZY.xml
 'Images/MMCPZY.jpg Labels/MMCPZY.xml\n'
'Images/MMCPZY.jpg' 'Labels/MMCPZY.xml'
Images/LCW6RB.jpg Labels/LCW6RB.xml
 'Images/LCW6RB.jpg Labels/LCW6RB.xml\n'
'Images/LCW6RB.jpg' 'Labels/LCW6RB.xml'
```

As annoying as it was, it was that small `'\r'` who caused the path error. I could not see it in my console until I write the script above. My question is: Why is this `'\r'` even there? I did not create it. Something somewhere added it there. It would be helpful if someone could tell me what is the use of this small '`r`' , why did it appear in python2 and not in python3 and how to avoid getting bugs due to it.

Comment: `\r` is a carriage return (a kind of whitespace). It's probably in the file you're reading. You can remove it from the end of a line with [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Comment: Better yet, fix whichever tool or process created this file with DOS line endings.

Comment: better yet, make your program robust to those characters as they're just noise in your case.

Comment: Better better yet yet, don't use Python 2 any longer.

Answer (score 2):

there's probably a subtle difference of processing between Windows text file in python 2 & 3 versions.

The issue here is that your file has a Windows text format, and contains one or several carriage return chars before the linefeed. A quick & generic fix would be to change:

```
img_file, anno = line.strip("\n").split(" ")
```

by just:

```
img_file, anno = line.split()
```

Without arguments `str.split` is very smart:

- it splits according to any kind of whitespace (linefeed, space, carriage return, tab)
- it removes empty fields (no need for `strip` after all)

So use that cross-platform/python version agnostic form unless you need really specific split operation, and your problems will be history.

As an aside, don't do `for line in lf.readlines():` but just `for line in lf:`, it will read & yield the lines one by one, handy when the file is big so you don't consume too much memory.

Comment: Not so subtle, actually; Python 2 required `open(filename, 'Ur')` for the behavior wich is now the standard default mode for text files in Python 3.

Comment: interesting. I'm more used to windows, where it is different too since \r are removed when using text mode.